# Error at System.out.print(word.charAt(count))

Tags: java, charat

I'm trying to get a user input and print the word starting from the last character and adding the previous one to the next line with one less space in the front, looking like it's aligned to the right.

but it shows there's an error in:
System.out.print(word.charAt(count));

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter word to print: ");
String word = input.nextLine();
System.out.println();

int line, space, count = -1;

for (line = word.length(); line > 0; line--){

  for (space = line; space > 0; space--){
    System.out.print(" ");
    count++;
    }

  for ( ; count <= word.length(); count++){
    System.out.print(word.charAt(count));
  }

System.out.println();
}
```

error shows as:

```
Exception in thread "main java.lang.String.IndexOutOfBoundsException: S
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:22)
```

Comment: Please clarify what error you are receiving. Please tell us what you found when you researched this error.

Comment: "_but it shows there's an error_" Please do tell us what it is instead of making us guess.

Comment: You have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` cause by the fact that you try and get a character from the `String` beyond it's current length, remember, `String` is zero indexed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your last `for` loop. `count <= word.length()` means that the loop will continue to run as long as `count` does not exceed `word.length()`, which is a problem because the index for each character in a `String` starts as 0, not 1.

So, for instance, if you enter a five-letter word, the `for` loop will run until `count` equals 5. On its final iteration, when `count` is equal to 5, it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `word` only goes up to index 4 (the first character is at `0`, the second is at `1`, and so on, meaning the fifth character is at index `4`).

So, instead of the exit condition for that `for` loop being `count <= word.length()`, it should be `count < word.length()`.